Using a form input with capture=camera, is that image stored on the picture-taking device?
I would like to create a web app that does not save an image to a user's phone when taken, as an (admittedly imperfect) guard for IP for my workplace. I know I can set up a JavaScript capture from video stream, but if I use
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

It does not seem to save to my phone's camera roll. Is it stored somewhere else on the device? Or does it actually directly upload it to the server?

Think you might be missing some example code in your question. Can you clarify?

"Or does it actually directly upload it to the server?" - nothing gets uploaded, until the user submits the form, or some JS does it in the background, once the field's value/content changes. But whether the browser holds the image in memory until then, or it gets stored somewhere on the device - that's probably an implementation-specific detail.
